# Android: installing fuse

Tags: android, fuse

I am trying to install fuse-android library to an Android virtual device. To do that I first tried to make a fuse kernel module support for AVD. My OS is Linux. I took this module from this path:

`/lib/modules/3.2.0-23-generic/kernel/fs/fuse/cuse.ko`

and copied it to the `/dev` directory of the AVD. Then in the AVD console I executed the command: `#insmod cuse.co`. After that I received the next message: `init_module 'cuse.ko' failed (Function not implemented)`.

What could cause this problem? Maybe, I am trying to use a wrong module? Perhaps, somebody can tell me what are the right steps for configuring fuse-android lib? I did not manage to find anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you build that module against the sources (or at least headers) of the kernel running on the emulator, using the same version of gcc (or at least a suitable one, which iirc the one provided in the ndk is not)?  Because if you just copied that module out of your desktop machine's /lib folder, it is definitely not going to work as it is for the wrong ABI, and most likely kernel version.

Comment: I really just copied it out. Thank you. Building and compiling of the android kernel with the fuse module support solved the problem.